# If I have -2 Intelligence modifier, do I get zero skill points if I take a level in Fighter?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter, character-levels, skills

I rolled a -2 Int mod on a level 1 fighter today and if i'm not mistaken that leaves me with 0 starting skill ranks, correct?

Comment: Welcome to site. Take the [tour]. The site's happy to check even basic math, but sometimes even basic questions can be more complicated than they appear. For example, this question's answer may be influenced by the race of the fighter and, if any, the archetypes the fighter possesses, both of which should probably be included in the question. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Pathfinder SRD:

> You apply your character's Intelligence modifier to:
>
> - ...
> - The number of skill points gained each level, **though your character always gets at least 1 skill point per level**.

Emphasis mine. Your level one fighter therefore has one skill point. Spend it wisely!

Comment: Thank you every one by the way it was a dwarf race therefore I knew it didn't get anu extra ranks. Sorry I had posted a duplicate.